# Как по клику пересчитать размеры блоков заданные при загрузке?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Всем привет. Столкнулась с такой проблемой. Есть блок с картинками, картинки разной высоты и ширины, так-же есть меню которое по клику уходит в лево (см. скрин). [image: Блоки] Вопрос в том что при загрузке страницы этим картинкам изначально дается определенная ширина и высота что бы в одну линию помещалась 4 изображения, но при нажатии на меню и когда оно уезжает в лево блоки не меняют размер а остаются такими же как и при первой загрузке, что в итоге на странице образует огромную дыру и потом если я меняю хотя бы немного размер браузера все начинает отображаться как надо. Следовательно вопрос: как мне заставить обновляться содержимое по клику меню? [image: блок] Помогите тупой бабе пожалуйста, мучаюсь 3 день не могу решить задачу(

Comment: Добавляйте воспроизводимый пример с html, css и js. По картинкам никто вам помочь не сможет(

Comment: @Hronoboy. Загрузи пример кода по правилам. Я понял твою проблему, но мне надо посмотреть на структуру. Полагаю что есть js. И полагаю (так как замечаю, что очень часто пишут тонну кода js, которая криво работает) можно и нужно упростить структуру, сделать лёгкой. Но! Загрузи код. Мы не экстрасенсы) и не джедаи.

Comment: @ Vladimir Rodichev http://scriptpie.com/cubeportfolio/live-preview/templates/projects/  вот пример на сайте - суть в том что при загрузке он считает размеры, но если фиксированная позиция трансформируется то он не знает откуда считать в реальном времени.